# AWS Glue spark application logs remain inprogress

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am using AWS Glue to run a PySpark job.  Job completes successfully (last step is to write dataframe to S3 and I do see that the files are created).

Problem is that I do not get "finished" Spark logs that I can view in the Spark UI.

In the Glue job details I have specified an S3 location for `Spark UI logs path`, and files do get written there with a name of `spark-application-<nnnnnnnnn>.inprogress`, but on completion of the job there are no final logs written (without `inprogress` extension).

Based on the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986784/why-doesnt-aws-glue-generate-spark-event-logs) I tried artificially extending the job time with a `time.sleep(2*60)` at the end, but it didn't make a difference.

I poked around a bit in the Cloudwatch logs and did find these log messages towards the end:

```
...
2023-10-11 16:25:20,274 INFO [Executor task launch worker for task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4)] mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil (Logging.scala:logInfo(61)): attempt_202310111625128823931779720627407_0001_m_000003_4: Committed. Elapsed time: 75 ms.
2023-10-11 16:25:20,276 INFO [Executor task launch worker for task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4)] executor.Executor (Logging.scala:logInfo(61)): Finished task 3.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 4). 2062 bytes result sent to driver
2023-10-11 16:25:20,885 ERROR [dispatcher-Executor] executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend (Logging.scala:logError(77)): Executor self-exiting due to : Driver 172.16.47.104:34325 disassociated! Shutting down.
2023-10-11 16:25:20,887 INFO [dispatcher-Executor] executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(61)): Driver from 172.16.47.104:34325 disconnected during shutdown
2023-10-11 16:25:20,889 INFO [CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend-stop-executor] sink.GlueCloudwatchSink (GlueCloudwatchSink.scala:logInfo(22)): CloudwatchSink: SparkContext stopped - not reporting metrics now.
...
```

Could the error message about driver dissociated and disconnected during shutdown be the reason for not finishing up the logs?
What could be causing that error?

**EDIT--------------**

I tried adding a delay at the end of my job as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67845963/12309386) but that didn't work.
Neither did adding `os._exit(0)`, which was recommended in [this answer on how to get a job to end gracefully](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72528222/12309386).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what eventually worked for me, YMMV.

I added the following to my job after `job.commit()`:

```
spark.stop()
time.sleep(60)
```

Neither one by itself seems to work, but the combination of the two result in another file being written without the `inprogress` extension, and my Spark UI is able to show me the details.